# Autoload classes if script need them. What if my php file is in another folder?

Tags: php, autoload

I found useful code that helps me keep my code readable.

```
function class_autoload($classname) {
    echo "class_autoload";
    @require_once ("class-{$classname}.php");
}

spl_autoload_register('class_autoload');
```

It loads classes, when server need them to run my code.
But now I have a problem:
One of my php files is in another folder then the rest. So I can't use this:

```
@require_once ("class-{$classname}.php");
```

And I can't change path because another php files will end work :/
What I should do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require_once` produces a fatal error if the specified file does not exist. The error control operator (`@`) does not change that. Use `include_once` instead, or test whether the file that you try to read actually exists.

You can call `spl_autoload_register` passing different function names every time. The auto loader will then call each of these functions to try to load the class. Use this feature to write a new function similar to `class_autoload`, but that knows where the class file is, that you cannot load with your current `class_autoload`. Call `spl_autoload_register`, passing that new function as an argument. Of course, if you do not change the `require_once` in `class_autoload`, that new function will never get called; your script will have died before the autoloader ever gets a chance to try your new function.

Also, take a look at [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md). This describes how class names *should* translate to directory- and filenames. Try to adhere to this standard when chosing where to put and how to name your class files. It makes life easier for you and for people who try to understand your code.

Comment: One more question: it is possible to get domain of my site using PHP and use absolute path? It will be useful if I move this files to another folder.